# Rails routes.rb syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-routes

I have searched and searched and I cannot find a page which spells out the syntax of routes.rb in Rails 3.  There are guidelines, overviews, even advanced examples but why isn't there a page that spells out the exact syntax of each keyword??  This page

http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/

contains a lot of advanced examples but doesn't take the time to discuss the behavior of all the examples given.  I would appreciate it if someone could point me to a page that breaks down the syntax of routes.rb.

Here is the problem I am trying to solve.  I have two models modelA and modelB.  The relationship is modelA has_many modelB and modelB belongs_to modelA.  I created the controller for modelB under namespace of modelA.  So in my rails app folder, I have

```
app/controllers/modelA_controller.rb
app/controllers/modelA/modelB_controller.rb
```

I want my routes to be as such:

```
http://localhost:3000/modelA/:modelA_id/modelB/  [index]
http://localhost:3000/modelA/:modelA_id/modelB/:modelB_id  [show]
etc.
```

I tried the following in routes.rb and none of it works:

```
resources :modelA do
  resources :modelB
end
--
resources :modelA do
  member do
    resources :modelB
  end
end
--
namespace :modelA do
  resources :modelB
end
--
match '/modelA/:modelA_id/modelB/action', :to => '/modelA/modelB#action'
```

I know some of the things I tried are obviously wrong but when you have spent 2 days on a single problem, anything goes!

Comment: Have you tried the rails' guides on routing? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason no one has a "definitive" guide on routing syntax is that it is pretty flexible so you could probably write a few chapters just on that one subject.  However, I would recommend: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

From your question, it sounds like you're namespacing `modelB` under `modelA` but you also want the `id` for `modelA` to be within the route itself.

So if your `ModelBController` looks something like:

```
class ModelA::ModelBController < ApplicationController
  # controller code here
end
```

then you can just do:

```
resources :modelA do
  resources :modelB, :module => :modelA
end
```

However, are you sure you want to namespace the controller like that?  If you just want nested resources like a typical `has_many` relationship, you don't need to be namespacing `modelB` under `modelA`.

Instead, you'd have:

```
/app
  /controllers
    /modelA
      # some files
    /modelB
      # some files
```

And your `modelB` controller would be:

```
class ModelBController < ApplicationController
  # controller code here
end
```

Then you could do

```
resources :modelA do
  resources :modelB
end
```

Comment: Thanks!! I really didn't intentionally create modelB under modelA.  I was trying to figure out how to nest resources so that `http://myserver/modelB` is not accessible and is only accessible through `http://myserver/modelA/:modelA_id/modelB` and somewhere someone had recommended using `rails generate controller modelA/modelB`.  I realize now that I should achieve my original goal using routes and not by scoping the controllers.  You can tell I am a newbie.  That said, under what situation is scoping recommended??

Comment: Namespacing the controllers like that is more for organizing them and is just a matter of preference.  It just adds a little more complexity to the routing which you probably don't need right now.  I would recommend staying with the simple nested resources route.